# install gdebi package using chef

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra

I'm having trouble installing a custom debi package on Ubuntu using Chef.  I've tried several different resources, including apt_package, dpkg_package, package, as well as the cookbook "gdebi_package".  None of the package resources appear to work.

Using the gdebi cookbook, I tried the following:

```
package 'internalapi' do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Gdebi
  source '/var/tmp/internal-api_0.0.1_amd64.deb'
  action :install
end
```

and

```
gdebi_package '/var/tmp/internal-api_0.0.1_amd64.deb' do
  action :install
  version '0.0.1' 
end
```

But I get the following error:

> *Chef::Exceptions::Package: No candidate version available for /var/tmp/packagename.deb*

I've also tried using the execute resource, such as:

```
execute 'packagename' do
  cwd '/var/tmp'
  action :run
  command 'sudo gdebi packagename.deb'
end
```

But get the following error:

> STDERR: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Has anyone had success using Chef to install a custom deb package using gdebi?  Thanks.

Comment: And a normal `package` resource with local file does not work ? (I mean without specifying a provider)

Comment: [dpkg_package](https://docs.chef.io/resource_dpkg_package.html) with `source 'filename.deb'` should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Or is there a reason that you really need to install it using `gdebi`?

Comment: I believe it needs to be gdebi, as it installs the package's dependencies along with the package.  I have tried to install it with a normal package resource as well as a dpkg_package resource and both were unsuccessful.  Thanks.